# How to return a []byte slice in Go to C

Tags: c++, c, go, cgo

I am trying to write a go function that returns a byte[] and use it in C.
This is main.go file:

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "unsafe"
)

//export hello
func hello() *C.char { 

    
    buff := []byte{1, 2, 3}
    res := unsafe.Pointer(&buff)
    result := (*C.char)(res)
    return result
}
func main() {

}
```

and Here is the C file:
test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hello.h"                       

int main(){
       
        char *c = hello();
        printf("r:%s",c);
}
```

But seems like what I return is still a Go pointer? Because I got this error:
panic: runtime error: cgo result has Go pointer

What should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I figure it out myself.
change the go function to this:

```
//export hello
func hello() *C.char { // 如果函数有返回值，则要将返回值转换为C语言对应的类型
    buff := []byte{1, 2, 3}
    res := C.CBytes(buff)
    result := (*C.char)(res)
    return result
}
```

in C:

```
int main(){
        int i;
        char *c = hello();
        for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
           {
               printf( "*(c + %d) : %d\n", i, *(c + i));
           }

}
```

output:

```
*(c + 0) : 1
*(c + 1) : 2
*(c + 2) : 3
```

Correct me if there is any problem

Comment: `C.CBytes` uses malloc (in C) to allocate space, then copies the bytes into it. If this is the solution you want, you need to free the memory in the C code after you've used it.

Comment: Thanks! I saw your answer before. But I got the same error when I change it to `res := unsafe.Pointer(&buff[0])`.  I'm not sure what's the problem?

Comment: When you write `[]byte{1, 2, 3}` the memory created to store that slice is managed by Go and its garbage collector. When you use `C.CBytes()` you allocate unmanaged memory. Strictly, you need to call `free(c)` in your C program when you no longer need the data, or the memory is allocated until your program ends. In your case it does not matter because its just a couple of bytes and `main()` terminates right where you no longer use `c` anway.